# How to add imputed data (w/ aregImpute) to a data frame?

Tags: r, missing-data, hmisc

My question is how do I go about adding the imputed data to the quakes.missing data frame?

I've created a reproducible example below.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(missForest) #load packages

data("quakes") 
quakes

quakes.missing <- prodNA(quakes, noNA = 0.1) #create missing values

summary(is.na(quakes.missing)) #confirm that data is missing

impute_quakes <- aregImpute(~ lat + long + depth + mag + stations, data = quakes.missing, n.impute = 5)

impute_quakes
```

Comment: Check out `impute_quakes$imputed`.

Comment: Thank you @ChirayuChamoli. I'm going to try to add the data with an apply function.

Comment: What do you by "adding the imputed data to the quake.missing" data frame? Do you want to add the data vertically (rbind) or horizontally (rbind)? Or, do you simply want to extract the multiply imputed datasets?

Comment: @Ahmedov what I meant was that I wanted to extract the imputed data sets so that I could perform an analysis on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 5 imputations, you'd have 5 full data frames, you can pull them out with a function like this:

```
fill_data <- function(impute = impute_quakes, data = quakes.missing, im = 1) {
  cbind.data.frame(impute.transcan(x = impute, 
                                   imputation = im, 
                                   data = data, 
                                   list.out = TRUE, 
                                   pr = FALSE))
 }
full_dat1 <- fill_data(im = 1)
full_dat2 <- fill_data(im = 2)
...
```

(also, I'm sure you are aware, but `Hmisc` also has a great function `fit.mult.impute` so you don't need to pull out full data frames in order to perform analyses)